# Why can names(x) be NULL, but colnames(x) are not?

Tags: r

From the docs `?name`:

> names(x)
> ...
> x an R object.
> ...
> (NULL is given if the object has no names, including for objects of types which cannot have names.)

But consider the following example:

```
tbl <- table(data.frame(x=c(1, 2), y=c(3, 4)))
names(tbl)
# NULL
colnames(tbl)
# [1] "3" "4"
```

My understanding is that this does not fit the documentation, or am I missing something?
The docs also state that "The default methods get and set the "names" attribute of a vector (including a list) or pairlist."
But then it should either return an error for a data.frame or the correct colnames and / rownames or both?

---

What I thought about:

```
x <- c(1:3)
names(x) <- letters[1:3]
df <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2), y=c(3, 4))
tbl <- table(df)

mynames <- function(x) { # cannot use names(x), as names(x) calls .Primitive("names")
  UseMethod("mynames")
}

mynames.integer <- function(x) {
  return(names(x))
}

mynames.table <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(names(x))) {
    r <- list(colnames = colnames(x), rownames = rownames(x))
  } else {
    r <- list(names = names(x), colnames = colnames(x), rownames = rownames(x))
  }
  return(r)
}

mynames.data.frame <- function(x) {
  return(list(colnames = colnames(x), rownames = rownames(x)))
}

mynames(x)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
mynames(df)
# $colnames
# [1] "3" "4"
# $rownames
# [1] "1" "2"
mynames(tbl)
# $colnames
# [1] "3" "4"
# $rownames
# [1] "1" "2"

names(tbl) <- letters[1:4]
mynames(tbl)
# $names
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
# $colnames
# [1] "3" "4"
# $rownames
# [1] "1" "2"
```

But

```
attributes(tbl)
# $dim
# [1] 2 2
# $dimnames
# $dimnames$x
# [1] "1" "2"
# $dimnames$y
# [1] "3" "4"
# $class
# [1] "table"
```

Comment: A class of "table" doesn't have a "names" attribute. It has a "dimnames" attribute. You can see that with `dput(tbl)`. So the docs are correct. A table is more like an array/matrix than a data.frame. And matrixes behave the same way: `m <- matrix(1:4, dimnames=list(letters[1:2], letters[3:4]), ncol=2); colnames(m); names(m)`. So `names()` doesn't know whether to default to rownames or colnames in such cases so it returns NULL since there are different cases were each of the names would be more appropriate.

Comment: @MrFlick see my edit, what I expected...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is based on the idea that data in R is a vector with attributes and the names are the names on that vector.

A data frame is a vector/list of columns so its names are the column names.

However, a table is not a list of columns.  It is a vector of cells and we know its structure from the dim and dimnames attributes so its names are the names of the individual cells.  tbl shown in the question does not have names on the individual cells but we could add names.

```
names(tbl) <- letters[1:4]

tbl # this does not actually show the names but they are there
##    y
## x   3 4
##   1 1 0
##   2 0 1

tbl[3]
## c   <--------------------
## 0 

c(tbl) 
## a b c d <--------------------
## 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: Your example helps, but I am still struggling, why the docs say "`names(x)` where  x is an R object". But to me the result only makes sense, when `x` is an array or list. See my edit...

Comment: `names` is a primitive generic so methods can be defined for classes so R itself does not necessarily define them.  If there is no method for a particular class then you get the default.  There may be restrictions on what R allows you to define as a name.  It may be that you can ask for the names of any object but you may just get NULL back.  For example names(sin) gives NULL.  The fact you can apply names to an object does not also imply that such an object can have names.